# Gnome tweak tool won't open

Tags: linux, debian

It seems like this is a result of changes I made following a couple Python tutorials, but I'm too new to Linux to know how to fix this.

Terminal output:

```
debian1@debian:~$ gnome-tweak-tool
bash: /usr/bin/gnome-tweak-tool: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This Problem Is Solved In [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899036/cant-run-remove-or-reinstall-gnome-tweak-tool)

Comment: Your Problem Is Solved In [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/901179/1077877)